# Creating a jSON object using php loop

Tags: php, json

I am trying to create a quick object for working with a graph I am making.

This is what the output looks like:

```
[
  ['Firefox',   45.0],
  ['IE',       26.8],
  ['Safari',    8.5],
  ['Opera',     6.2],
  ['Others',   0.7]
]
```

My code / loop that I need to use to create this data:

```
$series = Array();
foreach($segmentData->segment as $segment){ 

    echo $segment->segmentName . ' has ' . $segment->total . '<br />';
    //Need to create the data here

}
```

Comment: Why not use `json_encode`?

Comment: Just append a simple two-value array to your `$series` array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the reference array provided is not an object/non-associative you cannot create keys in PHP then json_encode it. The reference array provided simply needs a 2 element array for each segment.
Simply create the data using a PHP non-associated array. Then json_encode the data. This should match exactly the reference array you provided.

```
$output = array();
foreach($segmentData->segment as $segment){ 
    array_push($output, array($segment->segmentName, $segment->total));
}
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: This didn't create the output that I listed :/

Comment: `[[{"0":"SSP II"},{"0":"3"}],[{"0":"Limitations"},{"0":"2"}],[{"0":"Disputes"},{"0":"2"}],[{"0":"PSS"},{"0":"4"}],[{"0":"Debit Card"},{"0":"5"}]] `

Comment: Odd... this means your variables you provided are objects themselves and not simply text/numbers. what does var_dump($segment->segmentName) and var_dump($segment->total) output?

Comment: `array_push($output, array((string)$segment->segmentName, (string)$segment->total));` this fixed it :)

Comment: Is there a way to not include quotes around the numeric value though ? `[["SSP II","3"],["Limitations","2"],["Disputes","2"],["PSS","4"],["Debit Card","5"]] ` the quotes around the numbers throw it off

Comment: blah, done haha; thank you! `$theData = json_encode($output, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`

Answer (score 1):

to create json object add the values to an array in loop and then using `json_enode` do like below

```
foreach($segmentData->segment as $segment){ 

        $final[$segment->segmentName]=$segment->total;
    }

    $final = json_encode($final);
```